# Cost of visit paid by spouse, do I need to provide his proof of earnings?

Tags: paperwork, proof-provenance-of-funds

If my spouse is paying for the trip but we dont have joint account, meaning I have my own bank account and he has his own, does it mean I need to provide proof of earnings for my spouse? Like paylips and bank account statements?

Answer (score 3):

Yes, it does. Your spouse needs to show that he can afford the commitment and the source of his funds. See [Should I submit bank statements when applying for a UK Visa? What do they say about me?](https://travel.stackexchange.com/questions/66104/should-i-submit-bank-statements-when-applying-for-a-uk-visa-what-do-they-say-ab)

Comment: Will his payslips,bank statements will be enough?